Why does `std::mem::size_of::<Vec<[i32]>>()` fail to compile?
Consider the fact that the following code compiles and runs successfully:
println!("{}", std::mem::size_of::<Vec<i32>>()); // 24
println!("{}", std::mem::size_of::<Vec<char>>()); // 24
println!("{}", std::mem::size_of::<Vec<&str>>()); // 24
println!("{}", std::mem::size_of::<Box<i32>>()); // 8
println!("{}", std::mem::size_of::<Box<char>>()); // 8
println!("{}", std::mem::size_of::<Box<[i32]>>()); // 16
println!("{}", std::mem::size_of::<&[i32]>()); // 16
println!("{}", std::mem::size_of::<*mut *const [i32]>()); // 8

Now consider the following code:
println!("{}", std::mem::size_of::<[i32]>());

This fails to compile with error E0277 complaining that the size of [i32] is not known at compile time. I definitely see why this must be so, because [i32] is a i32 slice (i.e. a 'raw' slice in the sense given here [1], not a pointer to a slice (e.g. &[i32]), whose size is known at compile time (i.e. the size of a fat pointer = 2 * size_of(usize))).
But now consider the following code:
println!("{}", std::mem::size_of::<Vec<[i32]>>());

When you try to compile this code, you also get error E0277, complaining that the size of [i32] is not known at compile time.
Why is this the case? Consider again these lines from above:
println!("{}", std::mem::size_of::<Vec<i32>>()); // 24
println!("{}", std::mem::size_of::<Vec<char>>()); // 24
println!("{}", std::mem::size_of::<Vec<&str>>()); // 24

We clearly see that the size of Vec<T> is not dependent on the size of T, but is always the size a struct with 3 fields — pointer to data (8), length (8), capacity (8) — hence, 24.
So why does std::mem::size_of::<Vec<[i32]>>() not simply return 24, but instead fail to compile?
I know that Vec<T> requires T to implement Sized, and that that's the immediate reason. But I guess I'm more wondering about the deeper reason behind the design decision to make it the case that Vec<T> requires T to implement Sized.
Thanks!
[1] https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html#slice-layout

«I'm more wondering about the deeper reason behind the design decision to make it the case that Vec requires T to implement Sized.» Some instances of T must be stored in the heap-allocated storage, thus the size of T must be known in order to allocate a storage with a sufficient size.

Vec<[i32]> is an impossible, nonsensical type, determining the size of nonesense isn't well defined.

The line which fails to compile (println!("{}", std::mem::size_of::<Vec<[i32]>>()); ) is about the size of a Vec<[i32]> type, so I'm not sure I understand you when you say "the size of Vec isn't in question".
Note that the mere fact that [i32]'s size is unknown at compile time can't be the whole story, because it doesn't explain why size_of::<&[i32]>() and size_of::<Box<[i32]>>() are unproblematic.

Both Box<[i32]> and &[i32] aren't nonsensical.

@cafce25 If Vec<[i32]> were nonsensical, the error would have been E0747 ("... provided when a type is expected"), not E0277. Try e.g. println!("{}", std::mem::size_of::<Vec<[]>>()); which is genuinely nonsensical.

It's nonsensical because a heap allocated sequence of unsized things doesn't make sense… It's still valid syntax.

To expand on what cafce25 said, the very reason for Vec's existence is to store items one by one. For that to work, the size of the items must be known. This is why Vec requires Sized, and Vec<SomethingUnsized> fails to compile. size_of is just the collateral victim here - the compiler isn't aware that size_of::<Vec<JustAboutAnything>> could return 3*size_of::<usize>() to implement that kind of shortcut, it just doesn't work like that.


But I guess I'm more wondering about the deeper reason behind the design decision to make it the case that Vec<T> requires T to implement Sized.

It is very simple to answer if you think about how arrays work. After all, Vec is just a heap-allocated dynamically-sized array.
Arrays allow random access (i.e. indexing), which is done by offsetting the pointer to the start of the array by the index times the size of the elements. If not all elements are the same size or if that size is not known, indexing just can not work. From that, it should be pretty clear why Vec<[i32]> (or indeed [[i32]; 4]) is a nonsensical type.
(If indexing was not a requirement, it would be possible to just put slices one after another in memory, but it would be a pretty useless structure without knowing where each slice ends and the next one begins. That is better represented by a one-dimensional (flattened) array/slice, with a separately maintained list of starting indices. But at that point, you could just make an array of pointers to individual slices.)

The Sized requirement could not be relaxed on T in the struct definition, even if it was kept everywhere else, because of the Drop implementation: that implementation requires doing things with the array, so it requires the Sized bound; but Drop must either be implemented for all possible instantiations of generics, or none.

@jthulhu You're right, I missed that! I removed that part from my answer.

The problem lies in the type expression Vec<[i32]>. That's not a valid type, because Vec<T: Sized>, yet [i32]: !Sized. It has nothing to do with size_of part of that line.
